# $ \lim_{T_{0} \to +\infty} {\int_{\Gamma_{T_0}}df+\frac{\sin 4z}{z}dz} $

Tags: calculus

$$ \text{Here we get }f(x,y,z)=\cos y e^{\sin x-x^2-y^2},\text{try to find}\lim_{T_{0} \to +\infty} {\int_{\Gamma_{T_0}}df+\frac{\sin 4z}{z}dz} $$
$$\text{where }\Gamma_{T_0}:x(t)=te^{t^{2018}},y(t)=t^2 \sin (1+t^{2019}),z(t)=\phi (t),\phi\text{ is smooth here },\phi(0)=0,\phi'\geq 1,t\in[0,T_{0}] $$

Answer (score 0):

$$ df=\cos ye^{\sin x-x^2-y^2}(\cos x-2x)dx-e^{\sin x-x^2-y^2}(\sin y+2y\cos y)dy+0dz $$
The original limit would be $$ \lim_{T_{0} \to +\infty} {\int_{0}^{T_0} (\cos ye^{\sin x-x^2-y^2}(\cos x-2x)\frac{dx}{dt}-e^{\sin x-x^2-y^2}(\sin y+2y\cos y)\frac{dy}{dt}+\frac{\sin 4\phi}{\phi}\frac{d\phi}{dt}})dt $$
$$ \lim_{T_{0} \to +\infty} {\int_{0}^{T_0} \{e^{\sin x-x^2-y^2}[(\cos x\cos y-2x\cos y)x'-(\sin y+2y\cos y)y']+\frac{\sin 4\phi}{\phi}\phi'}\}dt $$
$$ =\lim_{T_{0} \to +\infty} {\int_{0}^{T_0} \{e^{\sin x-x^2-y^2}[\cos y(\sin x-x^2-y^2)'+(\cos y)']+\frac{\sin 4\phi}{\phi}\phi'}\}dt $$
$$ =\lim_{T_{0} \to +\infty} {\int_{0}^{T_0} e^{\sin x-x^2-y^2}[\cos y(\sin x-x^2-y^2)'+(\cos y)']dt+\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin 4\phi}{4\phi}}d4\phi $$
$$ =\lim_{T_{0} \to +\infty} {\int_{0}^{T_0} e^{\sin x-x^2-y^2}[\cos y(\sin x-x^2-y^2)'+(\cos y)']dt}+\frac{\pi}{2} $$
$$ =^{\text{integrate by parts}}\lim_{T_0 \to +\infty}\cos ye^{\sin x-x^2-y^2}\bigg|_{0}^{T_0}+\frac{\pi}{2} $$
$$ =\frac{\pi}{2}-1 $$